# LibGDX Texture array won't work

Tags: arrays, libgdx, textures

I am trying to use LibGDX to make a simple game in which once i clicked on the screen the Texture "eggs" should change to the next one in line. Yet every time i touch the screen the app crashes

```
Texture[] eggs = new Texture[5];

}

@Override
public void render() {


    if (Gdx.input.justTouched()) {

        eggs[i] = new Texture(String.format("pic_%d.png", i++));
        batch.begin();
        batch.draw(eggs[i], Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2 - eggs[i].getWidth() / 2, Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 2 - eggs[i].getHeight() / 2);
        batch.end();
    }
}}
```

Comment: Where is `i` coming from? What says the stack trace?

Comment: What exception you get?

Comment: You need to edit your post to include the error, otherwise we cannot help much. If the crash error is `java.lang.NullPointerException` then it means that `i` has not been initialized in your code, so add `public int i = 0;` outside of the render method. If your error is `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` then it means that `i` is too big or too small, it must be within the range of  between the values of 0 and 4.

Answer (score 0):

`eggs[i]=...` gets evaluated first and gets a Texture object, `i` is incremented afterwards. Therefore taking it as the index actually refers to an uninitialized Texture element in your array.